# Как выбрать первую страницу в пагинации

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть пагинация на комментариях (стандартная) вот код

```
    function rabaPaginationCommentsArgs() {
    return [
        'show_all' => false, // показаны все страницы участвующие в пагинации
        'end_size' => 2, // количество страниц на концах
        'mid_size' => 2, // количество страниц вокруг текущей
        'prev_next' => true, // выводить ли боковые ссылки "предыдущая/следующая страница".
        'prev_text' => __(' '),
        'next_text' => __(' '),
        'add_args' => false, // Массив аргументов (переменных запроса), которые нужно добавить к ссылкам.
        'add_fragment' => '', // Текст который добавиться ко всем ссылкам.
        'screen_reader_text' => __('Posts navigation'),
    ];
}
```

но как только заходишь на страницу с выводом коментарий то оказываешься на последней странице, вопрос как сделать что бы оказывался на первой, спасибо :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем я нашел проблему, в админке в настройках > обсуждение нужно было выбрать "первая страница" а не "последняя")